# Google Drive API: Searching folders based on shared URL link - webViewLink

Tags: google-drive-api

Looking for a way to use the Search Files API to get a particular folder given the share URL of the folder.

Using this reference here for the various search term possibilities: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/drive.files.list/

For the 'q' variable, have tried:

1)  mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and properties has { key='webViewLink' and value='https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xyz123'}

returns empty list even though the value does exist

2)  mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'and webViewLink='https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xyz123'

returns 'Invalid Value' for the 'q' parameter

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve files and folders in a folder of `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xyz123`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? You can retrieve the folder ID from the URL of `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xyz123`. In this case, the folder ID is `xyz123`.

#### Pattern 1:

When you want to retrieve the files in the folder using the folder ID as follows. Please use it as `q`.

```
'### folder ID ###' in parents
```

#### Pattern 2:

When you want to retrieve the folders in the folder using the folder ID as follows. Please use it as `q`.

```
'### folder ID ###' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

#### Note:

- This query retrieves files under just the folder ID of `xyz123`. If the folder is nested and you want to retrieve all files with the folder structures, please retrieve recursively it by the script.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes these can work, however, they both assume that the folderID is embedded in the URL which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.  I can tell based on usage that the ID is in fact in the shared URL, but I don't see anywhere in the Google Drive or Google documentation that indicates that this will always be the case.

Comment: @tiend I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. The webViewLink includes the folder ID. But you don't want to include the folder ID. I cannot understand about this situation. So can I ask you about your goal? I apologize for my poor English skill.